# Loop and render data from 3 levels deep Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm consuming the following dataset from an external source, which contains a 3 level deep array of objects.

```js
const data = [
{name: "Molly", description: [
  {children: [{text: "Likes to run"}] },
  {children: [{text: "Likes ice cream"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes to cars"}] }
]},
{name: "Jay", description: [
  {children: [{text: "Likes to race bikes"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes cake"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes shoes"}]}
]}
]
```

I'm wondering if there's an elegant/smarter way to loop over all the array of objects all the way to the  `text` object so I could render its string value.

I'm looking for a vanilla JS solution where I don't end up with several `map()` functions chained together.

the end result would be to retrieve the `text` data and render it on a React component such as:

```js
const UserList({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((user) => (
        <SingleUser user={user} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
 
const SingleUser = ({user}) => {

const userDescription = // loop over and transform to render the text data here
return(
 <>
   <div>{user.name}</div> 
   <div>{userDescription}</div>
 </>
)
}
```

Comment: Each name have array with three text. Do what's text you like get? First or all ?

Comment: I'd like to get all of them and render each inside the separate `</div>`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to simplify it a bit, for example

```js
const data = [
{name: "Molly", description: [
  {children: [{text: "Likes to run"}] },
  {children: [{text: "Likes ice cream"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes to cars"}] }
]},
{name: "Jay", description: [
  {children: [{text: "Likes to race bikes"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes cake"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes shoes"}]}
]}
];

const flattenedData = data.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  description: item.description.flatMap(el => el.children[0].text)
}));

console.log(flattenedData);
```

Comment: this is cool - for my understanding, how come we only pass the first index of children? i.e. `el.children[0].text`

Comment: The second parameter of the map method is the index, so instead of using [0] you can use the [index] there.

Answer (score 4):

Inspiered in the @Shreevardhan answer but considering every element of the childrens arrays

```js
const data = [
{name: "Molly", description: [
  {children: [{text: "Likes to run"},{text: "To run very fast!"}] },
  {children: [{text: "Likes ice cream"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes to cars"}] }
]},
{name: "Jay", description: [
  {children: [{text: "Likes to race bikes"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes cake"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes shoes"}]}
]}
];

const flattenedData = data.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  description: item.description.flatMap(el => el.children).map(_el => _el.text)
}));

console.log(flattenedData);
```

Comment: this awesome, and covers the ground in case the `children` receive more than 1 item. How come you had to flatMap twice?

Comment: They are applying the second flatMap on the array returned from the first flatMap. Kind of a shorthand to bypass creating an extra variable.

Comment: Actually the second one is a regular `map`, I've corrected it...

Answer (score 4):

Use flatMap to simplify a matrix, then use the map in the User component to show the text of the descriptions

```
const data = [
    {name: "Molly", description: [
      {children: [{text: "Likes to run"}] },
      {children: [{text: "Likes ice cream"}]},
      {children: [{text: "Likes to cars"}] }
    ]},
    {name: "Jay", description: [
      {children: [{text: "Likes to race bikes"}]},
      {children: [{text: "Likes cake"}]},
      {children: [{text: "Likes shoes"}]}
    ]}
    ];
    
    const userData = data.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      description: item.description.flatMap(x => x.children[0].text)
    }));
  
  
  const UserList({ userData }) {
      return (
        <div>
          {userData.map((user) => (
            <SingleUser user={user} />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
     
    const SingleUser = ({user}) => {
    
    const userDescription = // loop over and transform to render the text data here
    return(
     <>
       <div>{user.name}</div> 
   {
     userData.description.map(text => { 
           <div>{text}</div>
     });
   }
     </>
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [
{name: "Molly", description: [
  {children: [{text: "Likes to run"}] },
  {children: [{text: "Likes ice cream"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes to cars"}] }
]},
{name: "Jay", description: [
  {children: [{text: "Likes to race bikes"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes cake"}]},
  {children: [{text: "Likes shoes"}]}
]}
];

let result = data.reduce( (acc, currentObj) => {
  let obj = {};
  obj.name = currentObj.name;
  obj.description = currentObj.description.reduce( (inneracc, innerObj) =>  inneracc.concat(innerObj.children[0].text), [])
  return acc.concat(obj);
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

We can achieve this using `.reduce()` and `.concat()` methods too. For more info, check out this link [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).